# How to write a simple webservice which returns JSON object on ajax call in jQuery Mobile

Tags: json, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm working on jQuery Mobile application which should get the data from the webservice based on the selected item in the form in jQuery mobile.

```
$("#catalogue").live('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "LifeService\log",
        data: "json="+$("prodcat");,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

This function doesn't return anything. When I simply run the webservice in browser with the value, I get the success message. Can anyone tell me how to call the webservice from jQuery Mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Where are experiencing a problem? Posting the code you've got so far would help. jQuery offers the `getJSON()` function you need, and you can then parse the resulting string back into a usable JSON object with `parseJSON()`.